# TypeError: must call as: npm.load(callback) when running NPX command locally from Google Maps API documentation

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack, google-maps-api-3

Trying to run the following [Google Maps API example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints) locally with this command:

```
npx @googlemaps/js-samples init directions-waypoints googlemapssample
```

But everytime I try to run the `npx` command locally, it fails after a few seconds and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: must call as: npm.load(callback)
    at Object.load (C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache\_npx\33944\node_modules\@googlemaps\js-samples\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:123:13)
    at Object.main [as handler] (C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache\_npx\33944\node_modules\@googlemaps\js-samples\cli\index.js:84:9)
```

I have npm version `npm` version `6.14.5` and `node` version `14.4.0`. Don't really understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently they're using a deprecated call to the npm.load(options, callback) method. NPM seems to expect only one callback argument (without an options argument).
My guess is that few people try to run it this way. I don't know if this cryptic Issue was opened to fix this problem: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples/issues/335

Comment: hmm okay, that's unfortunate. So I guess to "recreate" the sample locally...I'm just manually creating the files, copying the code over, and `npm install`-ing the libs? Seems tedious...but I guess I don't have an alternative if I want to run the sample locally.

Comment: Ahh I see on their README.md file on the Github repo I can do the following:

`# install the package`
`npm i -g @googlemaps/js-samples`

`# extract a sample to a destination folder`
`googlemaps-js-samples init map-simple destFolder`

`# run the sample`
`cd destFolder`
`npm i`
`npm run dev`

Comment: ...well even following those steps listed in the Github repo lead me to same error on the following command:

`googlemaps-js-samples init map-simple destFolder`